# How to get stylus and jade syntax highlighting in neovim

Tags: vim, pug, stylus, neovim

Currently if I open a jade or stylus file in neovim it stalls for up to 7 seconds, and then opens the file. It even has halfway decent syntax highlighting.

What's the proper way to get syntax highlighting for jade and stylus in neovim?

Comment: Have you ever tried *vim-pug* (https://github.com/digitaltoad/vim-pug) and *vim-stylus* (https://github.com/wavded/vim-stylus) plugins ?!!!

Comment: Those are the ones I use.

Comment: So you are on right track! just report the issues to plugin maintainers.

Comment: Without your `.vimrc` it's impossible to troubleshoot this. Also, try running Vim with a minimal `.vimrc` and see if your problem persists. More often than not it's related to a plugin conflicting or an esoteric setting you may have forgotten about. Both syntax highlighting definitions work quick and reliable on my end.